# PHP namespace confusion, class not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I have two classes in the same folder in own files. But when I am trying to extends one to another it is giving namespace and class not found error.

> **Info:** It is the first time I am extending class using namespace. Also nested namespace is new to me. `DB\CRUD` So may be I am doing
>   completely wrong with namespace.

### Error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DB\AT_Database' not found in /var/www/...
```

### DB class

***File: AT_Database.php***

```
namespace DB;

class AT_Database
{
    ...
}
```

### CRUD class

***File: AT_CRUD.php***

```
namespace DB\CRUD;


use DB\AT_Database;

class AT_CRUD extends AT_Database
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Exact error message please! Also, are you `include`ing or autoloading the AT_Database.php file?

Comment: I am including the class using `( glob( $this->classes_dir . "/*.php" )` I have added error message in question. Please have a look. Also if you thin `__autoload` would work better than I may use that.

Comment: Autoloading is more elegant as it frees you from having to add a bunch of `include` calls manually. It doesn't make any difference though if both are working as they should. Are you **100% sure** that the parent class is getting included? This should work fine as is.

Comment: Just a side note: extending the database class is bad coding style. You should favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: @deceze Yes I have cross confirm it after your comment and parent class `AT_Databse` is loading perfectly.

Comment: @prehfeldt I appreciate your feedback, So do you mean that I should instead instantiate it?

Comment: add '\' at beginning? Like 'use \DB\AT_Database;'

Comment: @RST doesn't make any difference..!

Comment: @CodeLover yes, the best way would be to use the dependency injection pattern to inject `AT_Database` into `AT_CRUD`. There are many dependency injection containers out there. [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) for example is a very lightweight one.

Comment: @prehfeldt I think you are right.. let me go through it.. Thanks a lot for key guidance. very very appreciated. BTW, as per your comment I found the issue why it is not able to find the class. See below answer please.

Answer (score 3):

This may be silly mistake or may be I have overlooked it (which I should not as a programmer) and that is loading sequence of the class.

***May be it's not worth to have as an answer but just adding so by chance in future it can help to someone who make such mistake.***

As I mentioned in one of my comment, I am using `glob` to auto load all class files to include.

```
foreach ( glob( $this->classes_dir . "/*.php" ) as $class ) {
    include_once $class;
}
```

Now my file names are `AT_CRUD.php` and `AT_Database.php`. Here I realized that php loads files in alphabetical order. So when I extends `AT_Database` class into `AT_CRUD` its never found.

This is just because php loads `AT_CRUD` first than `AT_Database` so either I have to instantiate the class into or to use something like dependancy injection as @prehfeldt mention in his comment.

Comment: Nicely explained. This illustrates another good reason why I prefer autoloading over such includes :)